# How to unionize two MongoDB from different hosts to one?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I want to make a one MongoDB instance that will include all the data from two others instances which run on the different hosts.
I know it is possible with import and export, but the data volume is too big, so it would take a lot of time. Are there any other ways?

Comment: If there's so much data, does it make sense to put it all on the same host?

Comment: We would like to get rid of unnecessary processes that load our processor.